# Android: Why does a "TextView" object need a reference to an activity as an argument?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The question is in the title

Example :

```
val textview = TextView(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Views (i.e. TextView) need reference to the `Context`.
Since `Activity` extends `Context` class, hence devs usually use `this` keyword to reference to context and fulfill the argument requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does a “TextView” object need a reference to an activity as an argument?

If you look at the [Source Code of Android's View](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java), the constructor takes and stores it in a variable named `mContext`:

```java
/**
 * The application environment this view lives in.
 * This field should be made private, so it is hidden from the SDK.
 * {@hide}
 */
protected Context mContext;
// ...
public View(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    // ...
}
```

That variable is useful for maintenance of its lifecycle, and used in many methods in the View class. As for example, [initScrollCache](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#3340), [sendAccessibilityEventInternal](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#3932), [onScrollChanged](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#6891) and many more methods do use them.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does a “TextView” object need a reference to an activity as an argument?

Because when you want to create a `TextView` programmatically you need to pass  `context` as an argument

For example `val textview = TextView(this)`

Here `this` refers to your current activity.